# Reference of Artin Conjecture

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, math-history

According to [this](http://www.algebra.at/multi.htm#ref1) web page around at 1925 E. Artin conjectured that the discriminant of a number field determines the number field uniquely (up to isomorphism). This is also claimed in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Schehrazad_Selmane/publication/270242614_On_the_Multiplicity_of_Discriminants_of_Relative_Quadratic_Extensions_of_Quintic_Fields/links/5832c52d08ae138f1c087ec5/On-the-Multiplicity-of-Discriminants-of-Relative-Quadratic-Extensions-of-Quintic-Fields.pdf) article and in [this slides](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/fieldstalk.pdf).

The thing is I find rather hard to believe that Artin could have ever conjectured such a thing, as counter-examples are not so hard to find (consider the fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3] {12})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3] {6})$). So is there any actual records of Artin making that conjecture?.

Comment: Are you sure those two fields have the same discriminant?

Comment: Yes, in general for a pure cubic field $K_{m}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{m})$ where $m=hk^2$ is not a perfect cube and $h,k$ are  relatively prime square free integers, we have $\text{disc}(K_{m})=-3^3 (hk)^2$ if $m$ is not $\pm 1$ module $9$. This is can be seen in Marcus Number fields pag 38. Also see http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/?start=0&discriminant=-972&count=20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In his first article after his thesis on quadratic function fields, namely
"On the zeta functions of certain algebraic number fields" (Math. Ann. 1923),
Artin cites Dedekind's article on pure cubic number fields in which the examples you mention figure prominently.

When Hasse proved in 1930 that there are discriminants D for which there are
arbitrarily many nonconjugate cubic fields with discriminant D he did not 
mention Artin's name. I couldn't find anything related to this "conjecture" 
in Hasse's correspondence or in his diaries.